# How to add description to the JMX Service Object's methods and parameters in JBoss?

Tags: jboss, jmx, jboss-4.2.x

Is it possible to have a description showing up in the JMX console for my MBean's methods and paramenters.

Right now this is how I see my MBean in the JBoss JMX Console:
[image]

Is there some annotation that can do that job for me?

Something like in the code snippet bellow (I just made the annotations up, not sure if they exist):

```
@Management
public interface InterestRateManager {
  @Description("Sets the interest rate")
  public void setInterestRate(@Description("The interest rate") double g);

  public double getInterestRate();
}
```

The end result would be to have the p1 have a meaningful name and to have the description.

Not super sure if this is relevant but I'm using JBoss 4.2.2 GA.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, it's possible. You have 2 primary options:

1. Implement your MBean as a [DynamicMBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/DynamicMBean.html). There's additional JBoss support for these through extending [ServiceDynamicMBeanSupport](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/javadoc/4.0.2/org/jboss/system/ServiceDynamicMBeanSupport.html).
2. JBoss implements a model called an [XMBean](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/JBoss_JMX_Implementation_Architecture-JBoss_XMBeans.html) which is probably preferable if you're only targeting JBoss. Basically, you can convert your existing code to an XMBean by simply providing the additional meta-data in the form of XML which can be embedded in the deployment descriptor or referenced as an external resource. See this page on how to [convert a standard mbean to an XMBean](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowDoIXMBeanIzeAnExistingStandardMBean).

Comment: So I can forget about doing this with annotations, right? Thx.

Comment: Ah yaeh... sorry. Blinders.... see http://weblogs.java.net/blog/emcmanus/archive/2005/07/adding_informat.html